# How do I create a new path variable?

Tags: java, android, windows, variables

I need to create a build file for android but first i need to create a new path variable in environment variables, How do I do that? I have accessed environment variables what is the next step do I need to create a user variable or system variable i need to use the path
"%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\

Answer (score 0):

Open your windows command line and enter:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\`

This will add `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\` to your PATH.

Close the windows command line and reopen. Enter `path` to check your new PATH variable has been set.

Comment: it says null when i enter path

Comment: Weird, if you have the environment variables window open via the control panel you can add it in there. You just click on 'path' within the table and click edit. Then add C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ to the end. Make sure that paths are separated by a  `;`.

Comment: It also sounds like your path is empty.